# Need a SVG file that is 150px wide, 20px tall, reads "THIS IS A TEST' with bold fonts, has a lime background

Tags: html, css, svg, gimp, inkscape

This is the code i have so far but it's not good

```
<svg
   width="200"
   height="13">
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <text
       style="font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;"
       x="0"
       y="13"
       id="">THIS IS A TEST</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

i am trying to get the text to fit perfectly in the box and etc.
 also need to add a background color to it.

Comment: I think a good tutorial is what you need, [have a look at this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started), the sample used there is actually very close to what you need.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but it seems there's not enough personal research shown in the question before asking it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can serve:

```
<svg
baseProfile="full"
width="200"
height="13">
 <g id="layer1">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
<text
    style="font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;"
    x="0"
    y="13"
    id="">THIS IS A TEST</text>
```